# Different Liquibase checksum on same files with cyrillic symbols

Tags: liquibase

I use liquibase for migrations and have sql files with cyrillic comments, like example.sql:

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset user:id1
create table example
(
    id            varchar(100) primary key
);

-- cyryllic comment here
comment on table kafka_cluster is 'Коммментарий к таблице.';
```

My changelog is yaml file like:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      # comment
      file: db/changelog/1.0.0/schema/example.sql
```

When i run application on different OS(my mac and on the linux server) i always got different checksums for same files.

Liquibase version:

```
    compile "org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.3.1"
```

I don't know why it happens, files are the same. All files are in the UTF-8 charset.

One of the answers for my question is to have all files in UTF-8 with BOM.
But it's not good for me - make sure that all sql files are with BOM.

Another solution is to move from yaml to xml.

Maybe there is a simpler solution?

Thanx.

Comment: If Linux is the environment and you just use mac for development, you may evaluate Liquibase docker to keep liquibase checksum creation all in *nix.  https://hub.docker.com/r/liquibase/liquibase

Comment: Yes, i can, but why there are different checksum?

Comment: I am not an expert but I believe either the checksum mechanism is different, or the file formats change when synching files down by say git?

Comment: It's very strange, cause when we rewrite migrations from YAML to XML format in liquibase - it's all ok.